# How to use WebView controls navigateToLocalStreamUri from WinJS/javascript

Tags: javascript, webview, windows-runtime, winjs

The WebView control is present after Windows 8.1 and from C#/VB/C++ it is documented and easy to use with the NavigateToLocalStreamUri call.  Yet in WinJS despite semi-documentation even on the MSDN part for Internet Explorer, there is no example.

The problem is we must pass an IUriToStreamResolver object to this call (Windows.Web does not even contain it in WinJS).  Yet in WinJS as far as I am aware it is not possible to derive from WinRT classes or implement these interfaces.  WinJS simply considers IUriToStreamResolver to be "Object" and the following code fails with "No such interface supported":

```
        var streamResolver = WinJS.Class.define(null, {}, {
            uriToStreamAsync: function (uri) {
                return Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri).then(function (file) {
                    return file.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.read);
                });
        }});
                var webViewControl = window.document.createElement("x-ms-webview");
                webViewControl.width = width;
                webViewControl.height = height;

                webViewControl.navigateToLocalStreamUri(webViewControl.buildLocalStreamUri("default", "/default.html"), new streamResolver());
                webViewControl.innerHTML = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
                window.document.body.appendChild(webViewControl);
```

My conclusion is currently that until Microsoft implements a wrapper object that supplies a javascript event, we must use a WinRT library, import the WinMD with our own object that allows us to wrap this code in either C#/VB/C++.  The class could be called UriToStreamResolverWrapper which has an OnUriToStreamAsync event which can be used through addEventListener/removeEventListener.  I could post code for this in C++ later yet it seems like Microsoft missed this one and really should be supporting it...

Answer (score 1):

According to a Microsoft blog, it is not possible: "In JavaScript apps, it is not possible to code an UriResolver object in JavaScript. However, you can use a resolver that is written in C++, C# or VB. For more details, see Scenario 4 in the WebView SDK Sample." at https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/07/17/whats-new-in-webview-in-windows-8-1/

This was implemented successfully on a working and tested model here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1080256/Using-the-WebView-controls-navigateToLocalStreamUr

I do not think that there is any way to do it without an object in a separate library that is in VB.NET/C#/C++/CX or native C++ until Microsoft provides a wrapper.